# PowerShell script to keep latest 10 images on self-hosted agent and remaining need to delete

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need a PowerShell script, always keep latest 10 images and other images need to delete automatically in linux based self-hosted agent VM. This script I need to pass via azure pipeline task like AZ CLI inline script. Can any one help me out this.
[image]
I need to keep latest 10 docker images

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the folder contain only images, or are there other file types?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be a base for a script.  I assume that you can look up elsewhere how to turn it into a proper cmdlet if you need that:

```
$path = "..."
$fileTypes = @('bmp', 'png', 'jpg') # * for all file
$filesToKeep = 10


Get-ChildItem ($fileTypes |% { join-path $path ('*.' + $_) }) | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending  | select -skip $filesToKeep | Remove-Item -Force
```

Use `CreationTime` over `LastWriteTime` if you prefer to go by date created, versus last modified.

Comment: This script is not helpful in my case, I need to keep latest 10 docker images and remaining need to be deleted.

Comment: Duh...  I'm slow this morning.  I no longer have docker installed, so I can't reproduce exactly, however, base up that output, you should be able to feed into SELECT -SKIP (remember the header.... it treats each line as plain old text), to get the remaining list, then parse out the image name and call the remove for each.

Comment: I'm not expect in power shell can please post the exact script for this

Comment: @gopinath I find your response to me trying to help very offputting.  I think you have me confused with a contractor.  I am not going to spend my time installing Docker again so that I can do your work for you.